# No errors but I can't see my data in database

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I'm inserting into MySQL using PHP, the Code goes through but when I query the database I find nothing in my Database. I can't figure out whats happening. I have five fields in my Db(ID,username,email,password,salt). Below is my PHP code.

```
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';
include 'functions.php';

$password = $_POST['password']; 

$random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()), true));

$password = hash('sha512', $password.$random_salt);
if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (username, email,  
password,salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"))

{    
$insert_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $email, $password, $random_salt); 

$insert_stmt->execute();
echo 'User added';       
}
else
{
echo 'Error couldnt add the user, Try again';
}

?>
```

And Below is my Form used for the registration.

```
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="Registration Process.php">
  <table width="373" height="130" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td width="180" height="27">Username (Name &amp; Surname)</td>
      <td width="140"><label for="username"></label>
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="23">Email</td>
      <td><label for="email"></label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="22">Password</td>
      <td><label for="password"></label>
      <input type="text" name="password" id="password" /><label for="salt">    </label> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="22">Salt</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="salt" id="salt" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="22">Click To register member</td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="register" id="register" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <!-- end .content -->
</form>
```

Comment: is this correct ?? action="Registration Process.php" with a space ?

Comment: how do all the other variables get populated? like `$username`, `$email` etc. - I don't see them being set in your code... also, you're not catching errors in your `$insert_stmt->execute()` function - see [example 3 on this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) for more info

Comment: @swapnesh yes I think its correct, But I'l change it for arguments sake and also change the file name. thanx

Comment: @ZathrusWriter oh I forgot to do that via the post method let me add it and I'l get back to you...

Comment: @ZathrusWriter thanx a lot its now working, It was because it wasnt getting the $username and $email values...I now added them it works. Thanx a lot :)

Comment: @Lord-David ok, I'll repost my comments as an answer, so you can accept it and this question can be resolved ;)

Comment: @ZathrusWriter Put it as answer and Lord-David please accept that !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not be getting your `$username`, `$email` and other variables from `POST` array in your code.

Furthermore, you're not catching errors in your `$insert_stmt->execute()` function - [see example 3 on this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) for more info.